# Density problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, radiation, density

> Spacecraft are commonly clad with aluminum to provide shielding from radiation. Adequate shielding requires that the cladding provide 20. g of aluminum per square centimeter. How thick must the aluminum cladding be to provide adequate shielding?

So I know that generally accepted value for density of aluminium is 2.7g per cm^3. The answer states it is (20g/cm2) / (2.7g/cm3)to get a thickness of 7.4cm. But this makes no sense to me. Why would you divide an area by density to get height???

Comment: You're not dividing an area by density to get height, you're diving surface density by volume density to get the height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume we have an aluminium plate that is $1 cm$ thick. An area of that plate that is $1cm^2$ will have a volume of $1cm^3$ and therefor a mass of $2.7g$.

To get the correct shielding we want that $1cm^2$ to have a mass of $20g$. To do that we need to make the plate $20/2.7 = 7.4 cm$ thick.

This is exactly the same as you did when you divided $\frac{20g}{cm^2}$ by $\frac{2.7g}{cm^3}$. The $g$ and $cm^2$ cancel out, and you end up with $cm$ for the thickness.

Comment: "will" have a volume of 1cm^2?

Comment: @TheFlyingBLOcK.- it clearly says $1 cm^3$

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not dividing area by density --- it is dividing surface mass density, in units of g/cm$^2$, by volume mass density in g/cm$^3$. The mass units will cancel and the quotient will have units of centimeters, measuring thickness/height.

Comment: But intuitively why would you divide surface mass density by density?

Comment: Think of it this way. Say you have a rectangular prism with dimensions 3cm x 4cm x 5cm. The volume of this box is $V = lwh = (3)(4)(5) = 60$ cm$^3$. This same volume can be found by multiplying the area of one of the surfaces by the height, e.g. an area of $(3)(4)=12$ cm$^2$ times a width of $5$ cm, giving 60 cm$^3$ again. Work this logic backwards and you can determine the height of the prism from its volume and the area of one surface. It's the same here, but with mass. Ultimately my example and your problem reflect the integral relationship between volume and area, $V = \int A(x)dx$.